# Custom Layout as Map Marker

Tags: android

i am trying to add Custom Layout as Marker and i am following [this](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/), but i am getting output as red patch which is the background of Parent layout!

if i don't put the background the marker does't even appears.
Here is what i have tried so far, please help.

location_marker.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/red"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<pgapp.com.rodionsolutions.pg.pgadmin.widgets.RegularTextView
    android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:text="Area Name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageMarker"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_point_to_down"/>
```

and then in Java

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title(pgDTOList.get(i).getPgName())
                            .snippet(pgDTOList.get(i).getAddress())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker))));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20.0f));
```

this the method to create Layout as bitmap

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

but the output is

[image: This this the output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Add in google map like this

```
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getActivity(), markerView)));
```

Marker mar = mMap.addMarker(marker);

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this lines, it make image not show also don't affect your code

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
```